# URL gives 404 ..Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url

I'm having issue with my url..i actually was trying to remove # tag from my url..which is done but the problem is now if i'm having url like this

> http://localhost/xyz

it redirects me to

> http://localhost/xyz/home

but the if i try and refersh the same page

> http://localhost/xyz/home

it gives 404

any one knows how to solve it..

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the hashtag tells the browser to use an angular route. If the hashtag is missing (which it will be on a refresh) it will be taking the user to a page that does not exist. You need to leave the hashtag in

Comment: Can you share your jsfiddle to check the exact problem ?

Comment: @Loading.. sorry but I have no idea how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

so actually now i'm able to open http://localhost/xyz/home directly with **url rewrite** which will point to my index.html.but now the bigger issue is whenever i'm trying to run my project it says unable to start debugging and none of my service is getting called it says 405(metod not allowed).i tried iisrest.but no luck.
so if you have any ideas,please share and thank you.